# Error key Project Typhoon

Tags: github, key, typhoon

I downloaded the project “Typhoon-example" on github.

I now want to insert my key, but I visualize a very long key.

In the project the key is formed by 24 characters, my key is 40 characters. If I insert my key into the project, the app crashes. I have a free account on worldweatheronline.com.

What do I do?

http://imageshack.com/a/img537/276/N7wtNq.png

Answer (score 0):

The Typhoon sample apps incorrectly assume that you've supplied a valid key. When using your key (emailed to us privately), the following response is returned:

```
<error>
  <type>KeyError</type>
  <message>'/(your key)' is not a valid key for 'Free-Weather-API'</message>
</error>
```

Regarding the problem where the sample app assumes you've supplied a valid key, instead of printing a friendly message: We've [created an issue in Github](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-example/issues/21), and will shortly address it.

Meanwhile, you can proceed by providing a valid key.

You may have debugged this problem yourself in one of two ways:

- Print the response from the server
- Paste the following URL into your browser: `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?num_of_days=5&key=YOUR_KEY&q=Phnom%20Penh&format=xml`

**Update:**

It appears that newly created keys for the weather API that the sample app uses only work with their version2 API. Just now a Typhoon contributor has kindly patched the Objective-C sample. We'll follow with the Swift example shortly.

Comment: You should not post your API key on a public forum. (Even if invalid)

Comment: Ok, but the code into link, I will not use into my App; but why did not it work?

Comment: Response message Error:  KeyError '7a35b6f58ee....' is not a valid key for 'Free-Weather-API'  What do I do?